# php http_referer

Tags: php, facebook

I have this part of a program:

```
$refferer  = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) 
&& ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != ""))
? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : "Unknown";
```

to get info on people visiting my site. But I would like to know if I can extract more information from the referer? For example if someone is connecting to my website through a facebook link I get the referer as http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmypage.net%2Ftest.php&h=PAQHD6FDUAQGrvZ32aZTbU9b...
Is there a possibility to get the facebook user name as well ?

Comment: could be shortened to `$refferer  = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : "Unknown";`

Comment: and it seems your question has nothing to do with referer itself

Comment: If you want to access the user name aswell, you have to add the facebook api on your site and extract the information. This information is not passed in any header (as far as I know)

Comment: to anyone who feel volunteer enough to edit questions. Please, do make your edit sensible, not just some case change but read the question and write a title to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible. If you want to access information from Facebook, you need to register your application on Facebook and use their [OAuth 2.0 API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot extract user information from the referring URL. You may wish to consider using [Facebook's Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/) to collect user information.

With Open Graph, you can add social plugins to your site, create Facebook applications, and interact with your users via the Facebook API.

Answer (score 1):

The referrer of l.php is specifically there to prevent sites from scraping private user data via analysis of the referrer headers. There should be no way around this.